# How to bind spacebar key to a certain method in tkinter (python)

Tags: python, methods, python-2.7, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am working on a project in python, and I made a method to draw a specific thing in tkinter. I want it so that whenever I press the spacebar, the image will redraw itself (run the method again because I coded the method so that it could redraw over itself). How exactly would I bind the spacebar to the method so that the program would run, draw, and re-draw if I pressed the spacebar?

for example, i want it so that whenever I press space, the program draws in a random location on the canvas:

```
from Tkinter import *
from random import *

root=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(root,width=400,height=300,bg='white')
def draw():
    canvas.delete(ALL)# clear canvas first
    canvas.create_oval(randint(0,399),randint(0,299),15,15,fill='red')
draw()
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

how would i bind the spacebar to the method?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
from Tkinter import *
from random import *

root=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(root,width=400,height=300,bg='white')
def draw(event=None):
    canvas.delete(ALL)# clear canvas first
    canvas.create_oval(randint(0,399),randint(0,299),15,15,fill='red')
draw()
canvas.pack()

root.bind("<space>", draw)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you so much！ I looked at other questions but couldn't find something similar to what I needed. I guess adding the event=None was important.

Comment: glad to help. yeah, the callback function is called by Tkinter with a parameter, so it needs something to be passed in. And by setting it to None you can call it in line 9 without passing anything in.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
from Tkinter import *
from random import *

root=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(root,width=400,height=300,bg='white')

def draw(event):
    if event.char == ' ':
        canvas.delete(ALL)# clear canvas first
        canvas.create_oval(randint(0,399),randint(0,299),15,15,fill='red')

root.bind('<Key>', draw)

canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Basically, you bind your drawing function to some top-level element to the `<Key>` binding which is triggered whenever a key on the keyboard is pressed. Then, the event object that's passed in has a `char` member which contains a string representing the key that was pressed on the keyboard.

The event will only be triggered when the object it's bound to has focus, which is why I'm binding the `draw` method to the `root` object, since that'll always be in focus.

Comment: why would you choose to bind on `<key>` rather than `<space>`? It looks like you're making more work for yourself

Comment: @BryanOakley Yeah, I didn't realize that `<space>` existed until after I saw the other answer. I'm leaving my answer up in case it's useful, but I upvoted the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can aslo use `canvas.bind_all("<space>", yourFunction)`
That will listen for events in the whole application and not only on widget.